# I wrote code about split but can't understand some things in my code

Tags: python

I wrote this code and I have a doubt about something...

```
date = "2020-05-01"
d=date
d=d.split('-')
print('year : %s \n mon : %s \n day : %s' %(d[0],d[1],d[2]))
```

I wrote a code that separates `yr`, `m` and `d` and it works when I type `d = date`. but doesn't work when I type `d == date` and `date=d` or `date == d` too. I know there is a difference between `=` and `==`.

All I wanna know is the specific reason why it doesn't work.

When I type `d==date`, there is an error that says

> `NameError: name 'd' is not defined`

Why `d` isn't defined? I think `d==date` is defining process.

Comment: `==` is comparison, it doesn't define anything.

Comment: You said you know there's a difference between them, but it seems like you don't really. You need to review tutorials, this is a really basic language feature.

Comment: `stack overflow don't let me ask to you guys what's problem with my code` 1) "what's the problem with my code" is [off-topic](/help/on-topic) on SO 2) you were not able to ask questions most probably because you had asked too many low quality questions. You gained that right back after some time. But this question is again very low quality, so you're at risk to loose it once more. I suggest you read carefully [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [Creating a minimal example](/help/mcve) as well as [How much effort is awaited from SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)

Comment: For an in depth view of why you were probably banned (and might be again) from asking question, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: oh i didn't know this i'm new here Thanks for let me know this I will read it carefully thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In Python (and many other programming languages like php, Java, Groovy, JavaScript, Go, Perl, etc.), a single equal mark (`=`) is used to `assign` a value to a variable, i.e., it is an [`assignment operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements), whereas two consecutive equal marks (`==`) is used to check whether 2 expressions have the same value or are equal, i.e., it is an [`equality comparison operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons).

You can learn more about this [here](http://net-informations.com/python/iq/equal.htm#:%7E:text=Difference%20between%20%3D%3D%20and%20%3D%20in,expressions%20give%20the%20same%20value%20.&text=(x%3D%3Dy)%20is%20False,values%20to%20x%20and%20y.).

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmer mentioned `d==date` is a comparison and will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`
When you wrote `d=date`, that is assigning the value in `date` to `d`. Once done, d will have `2020-05-01`
Once you do the split, d will be an array like this `['2020', '05', '01']`
So, the print statement will give you `d[0]` of `2020`, `d[1]` of `05` and `d[2]` of `01`